# RetrieveUpdateDestroy and get_queryset how works

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i am learning drf and i little confused
in the urls.py i have

```
 path('todos/<int:pk>', views.TodoRetrieveUpdateDestroy.as_view()),
```

on the views.py

```
class TodoRetrieveUpdateDestroy(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = TodoSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Todo.objects.filter(user=user)
```

by logic i would add to filter like pk = self.kwargs[‘pk’] to send only one element Todo but it works and send only that ‘id=pk’ post without adding additional filter.Can u explain why please and how works RetrieveUpdateDestroy and get_queryset)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` doesnt execuate method     `def get_queryset(self):` in the first place

It has     `def get_object(self):` method which gets object by `lookup_fields` and query from query set method returned data again

So to get/update/delte single data,

You have to do like this:

```
class TodoRetrieveUpdateDestroy(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Todo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TodoSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    lookup_field = 'pk'
```

and your urls should be like this:

```
path('some-paht/<int:pk>/', TodoRetrieveUpdateDestroy.as_view(), name='some_name')
```